# navigationBar tintColor memory leak

Tags: ios

i will change navigationBar tintColor in viewWillAppear:
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor;`

in viewWillDisappear:
`NSLog(@"before retain count:%d", [tintColor retainCount]);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
NSLog(@"after retain count:%d", [tintColor retainCount]);`

`tintColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] retain];`

why nslog "before retain count" and "after retain count" is equal?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a kind of over-retention.

You assign a tintColor to the tintColor property of a UINavigationBar object.
This calls the setter of the UINavigationBar for the tintColor property which sends a retain-message to the given tintColor to be set.

I interpret the last line of code

```
tintColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] retain];
```

as the one where you create your custom tintColor. The last retain is the problem.
You can do it, but you have to release it somewhere after to get the reference counted memory cleanup to work.

Look at the class reference at [Apple UINavigationBar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) for the property declarations.

Comment: i release tintColor in dealloc